# Running init scripts concurrently

Tags: 20.04, init.d

In the older versions of Ubuntu we could start the init scripts parallel with modifying the file /etc/init.d/rc. This line was necessary:

```
: CONCURRENCY=shell
```

In the newer version 20.04 there is no file rc and i couldnt find any information about this. How can we run the init scripts concurrently in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Systemd has been Ubuntu's init for over four years. Convert your scripts into systemd services and targets. Systemd will handle the concurrency automatically

Comment: @user535733 Ok, thank you. I will try it.